# useLocation() is not working even inside the Router context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Bellow are my imports:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from './components/About';
import Works from "./components/Works";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
```

And bellow is the App component:

```js
function App() {
  window.document.body.style.background = "url('images/bg-image-3.png') no-repeat center center fixed";
  window.document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";

  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route path='/' element={ <Home/> }/>
          <Route path='/about' element={ <About/> }/>
          <Route path='/works' element={ <Works/> }/>
          <Route path='/contact' element={ <Contact/> }/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Now when I run the code my app is totally broken and I'm hit with the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

The issue persist even when I remove the `const location = useLocation()` declaration and use useLocation() directly to send props to `<Routes>` as given bellow:

```js
return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes location={useLocation()} key={useLocation().pathname}>
          <Route path='/' element={ <Home/> }/>
          <Route path='/about' element={ <About/> }/>
          <Route path='/works' element={ <Works/> }/>
          <Route path='/contact' element={ <Contact/> }/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Can someone please give me some hint as to what I should be doing differently?

Comment: Can you replace the import Statement with this one and see if it helps
`import { Router, Routes, Route, Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom"`;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Issue

The `App` component is rendering the `Router` that is providing the routing context, so `App` itself can't use the `useLocation` hook since it's ***outside*** the router.

## Solution

I am assuming that `Router` is *really* one of the higher-level routers (*`BrowserRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, etc*). Move the `Router` higher in the ReactTree than the `App` component in order to provide a routing context to `App` and allow proper `useLocation` hook usage.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

App

```
function App() {
  window.document.body.style.background = "url('images/bg-image-3.png') no-repeat center center fixed";
  window.document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";

  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
        <Route path='/works' element={<Works/>} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```